# Synchronizing child processes with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, buffer

I have a buffer with commands to be executed by task threads, but one of the commands must be executed by the main thread (parent). If I call 5 thread commands then 1 parent command and then 5 more thread commands, how can I make my program execute the first 5 thread commands (empty the buffer) then lock the buffer and execute the parent command and then unlock the buffer and proceed to execute the other 5 thread commands?

I think I need to user semaphores but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Show us what you have coded/tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.